# How to determine my database username/password

Tags: jakarta-ee, datasource

I have an app that I'm trying to figure out how to obtain the username/password used for the connection.

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="cmt_default_unit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>CMT</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Isn't this where the data should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a general practice to let the Web Container (i.e Tomcat) to manage Database Credentials, and let your application access Database connections through JNDI. Check your Container Console/Settings to get the info that you need.

The element jta-data-source points you to the JNDI name associated to a javax.sql.Datasource configured in your container. Verify what are your current settings.

PS: If you're using Tomcat, you can check [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Database_Connection_Pool_%28DBCP%29_Configurations)- If you're using Glassfish, [this](http://www.albeesonline.com/blog/2008/08/06/creating-and-configuring-a-mysql-datasource-in-glassfish-application-server/) could be useful.

Comment: I'm using GlassFish.... are you saying that CMT would be the name of a database connection?